# Regex replace only matched strings - C#

Tags: regex

I'm trying to work out how to use the Regex.Replace method for my needs, basically I need to find a particular word which doesn't have any "a-z" letters either side of it and replace only the matches with another word.

In the example below I search for all "**man**" occurrences and replace with "**coach**". I use this regex pattern "`[^a-z](man)[^a-z]`" which does capture what I want.

```
//String to search
"The man managed the football team"

//After using Regex.Replace I expect to see
"The coach managed the football team"

//But what I actually get is
"The coach coachaged the football team"
```

Comment: What about testing if it has a space in front or after `\sman\s` ?

Comment: Can you please produce a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since using the regex you've provided will not replace `managed` for me.

Comment: `Regex.Replace("The man managed the football team", "[^a-z](man)[^a-z]", "coach")` => `Thecoachmanaged the football team`, because you also replace the spaces around man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `\b` aka `word boundary`.

```
\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
```

Use `\bman\b`

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9/31

Your regex will replace `5` characters always.`\b` is a `0 width assertion` so it doesnt consume a character.

```
string strRegex = @"\bman\b";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @"The man managed the football team";
string strReplace = @"coach";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

Comment: Considering his original regular expression does indeed do what he wants (though yours is obviously better), I'm not entirely sure we've seen the entire question yet.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen OP's regex replaces <1 character>`man`<` character> so in effect it will never replace `man` but `5` characters which has `man` in between

Comment: Yes, you're right. Let me rephrase, it will not touch `managed`.

Comment: Hi, I have tried var res = Regex.Replace(str, "\bman\b", "coach");

Comment: @DavidMcQillan check edit.You need to use `@` or use `\\bman\\b`

Comment: Perfect thank you "var res = Regex.Replace(str, @"\bman\b", "coach");" worked